# how to retrieve/display last received sms from inbox in android

Tags: android

How to retrieve/display last received sms from inbox in android?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "inbox" in the Android OS and SDK.

Various SMS clients may have an "inbox". Few of those clients have a documented and supported API. The SMS client that is part of the Android open source project does not have a documented and supported API.